# Initializing a dynamically-sized Variable-Length Array (VLA) to 0

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, initialization, variable-length

The following line of code, which creates a variable-length array on the stack:

```
char name[length] = {'\0'};
```

Generates the following compiler diagnostics:

```
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
warning: excess elements in array initializer
warning: (near initialization for ‘name’)
```

What options are available to me for initializing VLAs? Am I forced to use a line such as:

```
memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
```

Instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you must write code for the initialisation of VLAs (which could be a `memset()` like you have described, or any other way that you care to).

It is simply a constraint in the C standard (§6.7.8):

> 1. The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of
>      unknown size or an object type that is
>      not a variable length array type.

Comment: Why can't I do it in the same line?

Comment: @Matt Joiner: It's just a constraint of the language - I've added the relevant text from the standard to my answer.

Comment: I think it is to avoid edge cases like this:
int arr[foo] = {1,2,3};
where foo could be 1 or 2. What happens then? :p
And to make it simple {0} is disallowed too, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can't argue with the standard. Not what I wanted to hear, but you can't expect bells & whistles from a 36 year old language.